# Unable to create Custom Logs in Tosca

Tags: tosca

I want to create custom log and generate the report based on those logs in Tosca.

for e.g.

I want to print log when the Application is launched successfully

Answer (score 0):

you can create a json or html file and you can write anytime you want it.
[File Operations](https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1330/en/content/standard_subset/automation_tools/file_operations.htm)